# Unity iOS build logs on windows

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, logging, build

We are developing a game with Unity engine for both Android and iOS, The unity android logcat is a huge help for us. I wanted to ask that, is there a way to access and view iOS logs similar to Android logcat so I could see the logs of iOS on my windows PC?

Comment: You can only do that with macbook/mac pc running xcode

Comment: Alright thanks. I'll test it.

Comment: you don't need xcode. you can use the application in MacOS called "console" to get the log output of any ios device attached to the mac.